# Problema con IF en sql

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

¿Cómo hacer una secuencia `SQL` para actualizar?

El problema es que en mi tabla `usuarios` tengo `userId, password y admin`.

Cómo hago en `SQL` para que:

- si `admin = 1` lo cambie a  `0`
- y si `admin = 0` se cambie a `1`

`where userId = (ID que le pasó yo)`.

No sé cómo usar el `IF` y no encuentro por internet como usarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo podrías probar con algo como:

```
UPDATE TableName SET admin=1 WHERE userId =1 AND admin=0
```

Y al revés seria:

```
UPDATE TableName SET admin=0 WHERE userId =1 AND admin=1
```

Otra alternativa seria algo como:

```
UPDATE TableName SET admin= CASE WHEN admin=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END WHERE userId =ID
```

Creo que algo como eso es lo que necesitas.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET admin = IF(admin = 1, 0, 1)
WHERE userId = ID
```

Comment: Gracias Edgar y Marcos son unos cracks